# Calling JavaScript function in MVC 5 Razor view

Tags: javascript, jquery, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have seen in another post that you can call a JavaScript function in your razor code like so:

```
@:FunctionName()
```

For me though this only outputs the actual words `FunctionName()`

Here is my view:

```
@model PriceCompare.Models.QuoteModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Quote";
}

<h2>Quote</h2>

@if (@Model.clarify == true)
{
    // do drop down loic
    @:ShowClarify();
}
else
{
    // fill quote
    @:ShowQuote();
}
<div class="clarify">

    You can see the clarify div
</div>
<div class="quote">

    You can see the quote div
</div>

@section head {

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(
            function ShowQuote() {
                $(".quote").show();
            },
            function ShowClarify() {
                $(".clarify").show();
            }
        );

    </script>
}
```

Is it because I have nested it in an `@if'?  Anyway around this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to put your javascript in a `<script>` tag, and you need to call the functions within their scope:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(
        function ShowQuote() {
            $(".quote").show();
        },
        function ShowClarify() {
            $(".clarify").show();
        }

        @if (@Model.clarify == true)
        {
            // do drop down loic
            ShowClarify();
        }
        else
        {
            // fill quote
            ShowQuote();
        }
    );

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks. Is the "@:" syntax a thing?  Was it discontinued?

Comment: The `@:` syntax just tells Razor to treat what follows as plain text. Within the context of a code block, this would be necessary to prevent Razor from attempting to run the `FunctionName()` method in a C#/VB context instead of a JavaScript context, where it actually exists.

Comment: @Guerrilla I didn't put this in Visual Studio, so it's possible that you may still need `@:` in front of the javascript function calls.

Comment: I believe it will need `@:` in front from what I've just been trying (so `@: ShowClarify();` and `@: ShowQuote();` )

Answer (score 3):

If you are passing any parameter to the JavaScript function, it must be enclosed with quotes ('').

```
foreach (var item in files)
    {
        <script type="text/javascript">
            Attachment(**'@item.FileName'**, **'@item.Size'**);
        </script>  
    }
```

Comment: You should use the code formatting options (select the code, Ctrl-k) to make sure that your code is displayed in the manner you intended it to be in your answer.  Also, it's better to use something from the question in your example to make it clearer what you mean.