# How to call javascript function in view in C# code on if else condition

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

```
    @foreach (var item in outcode)
                   {
             var outc = item;
             if (!codedata.Contains(outc))
             {
                 codedata.Add(outc);
             }
             else
             {
                 Fun();

             }
    }
//this is my C# code and here else condition call JavaScript function.

 function fun() {
                $("table").append('<tr><th><button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button">@Session["dd"]</button> </th> </tr>');
            }
```

// this is JavaScript function.
and this function call when else condition execute in razor code.

Comment: Can you share complete if/else statement?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling JavaScript function in MVC 5 Razor view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26736163/calling-javascript-function-in-mvc-5-razor-view)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function fun()

    {

    alert('You clicked '+ name +"!");

    }

    </script>

    <div>

        <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed">

            <tr>

                <th>Name</th>

                <th>Department</th>

                <th>Action</th>

            </tr>

            @foreach (Employee emp in Model)

            {

                <tr>

                    <td>

                        <a onclick="AlertName('@String.Format("{0} {1}", emp.FirstName, emp.LastName)')" href="#">@String.Format("{0} {1}", emp.FirstName, emp.LastName)</a>   

                    </td>

                    <td>



                    </td>


                </tr>

            }

        </table>

    </div>
```